# Hidden control is still challenging for validation?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

again experts,

On page loade, this dropdownList box, by deffault is invisible.

```
<td>
   <asp:DropDownList ID="LongDistance" runat="server" style="display:none;" >
      <asp:ListItem value="2">$2 per mile</asp:ListItem>
      <asp:ListItem value="4">$4 per mile</asp:ListItem>
    </asp:DropDownList>
  <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" id="RequiredFieldValidator4" 
   ControlToValidate="tripType" ErrorMessage = "please select long distance type!" 
   display="Dynamic" style="color: #FF0000; font-size: small" />
</td>
```

It becomes visible if certain condition is met.

My question is why is the user still being challenged to make a selection?

I would like for any invisible controls to NOT challenge user to make a selection unless the control is visible.

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Are you using JS to show/hide the DropDownList? If so then AFAIK the RequiredFieldValidator will still validate that control as its still on the page. I don't think it checks the visibility of the control. You may want to use the client side validation instead: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479045.aspx#aspplusvalid_clientside

Answer (score 0):

You should look for [validation Groups](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.basevalidator.validationgroup%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). If you have to validate differently on two different button.

Validation work as the data is post to the server even if it is not visible. And validation controls work on submit button and validate each input if there is any `validation controls` is being used.

Comment: Thanks a lot guys.

@jasonW, what happens if the control changes to visibility="true"?

Answer (score 0):

When you set the visibility of your control, you should also set the `Enabled` property of the `RequiredFieldValidator4` validator to match the visibility of the control it is validating. The `Enabled` property of the validator controls whether the validation fires.